# C# pointer - Static calling

Tags: c#

My short code :

```
class A
{
   private B b;
   public void b(){};
}

class B
{
   private void a() 
   {
   A.b();
   }
}
```

I can make void b in A static but I has some Controls like this.Controls.Add();

They must be static too, but I don't know how to implement it, can you show me or do we have a better way for this solution :)

Comment: The above code doesn't compile because the variable and method have the same name. Could you please post your actual code? That would probably help with answering your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could either do

```
class B {
    private readonly A instance;
    public B(A instance) { this.instance = instance; }
    private void a() {
        instance.b();
    }
}
```

or

```
class B {
    private void a(A instance) {
        instance.b();
    }
}
```

depending on what it is that you are trying to do.

(Note that you need to rename either `B b` or `void b` in `A`.)

Comment: It's great , can you name a good book learning about something like this ?

Answer (score 1):

To use control in static function, the control have to be static too.

```
private static Button StaticButtonObject = new Button();
public static void AddControl()
{
    StaticButtonObject.Text = "Button";
}
```